# Unable to connect to remote SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server

I'm so frustrated I'm going to give all of my rep points if someone can help me with this.

Scenario:

There was a domain name change and the development server had a SQL Server Express working. Since I have forgotten the SA password and was not able to login with any account from the new domain I decided to uninstall and re-install a new SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I installed SQL Server Express from WPI with management studio. After the installation I can open the local server with Management Studio, but cannot open from a remote Management studio.

What I did to try to figure out WTH is going on:

1. I made sure Remote connection was checked on the SQL Options "Connections"
2. I enable TCP/IP and Named Pipe on SQL Server Configuration for my instance `SQLEXPRESS`
3. I ensure that the port was OK on Properties of TCP/IP of the SQL Server Configuration, there were no value at first, so I manual entered 1433, stop, start the server, try to connect.

   a) I even try playing with the Active / Enable value, and with a stop, start, re-try in between every any changes.
4. Disable the Windows Server 2008 firewall, even added a manual rules for 1433.
5. Make sure the instance name was good on `hkey_local..\software\ms\sql\...` and the one I see on the local Management Studio, it's `SQLEXPRESS`
6. I can ping the server with its name or ip address, I even tried to connect with the IP address as well.

I'm just trying to connect from another server with another Management Studio, and here is the error I get:

> Cannot connect to DEVSERVER\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

The server is a Windows Server 2008 x64

What a time waster

TIA for any tips, can't believe what's happening.

UPDATE:

I telnet from the remote server on port 80 just to make sure it's not a network problem, and I got HTML result, since firewall is disabled, and tcp/ip is enabled, SQL Browser started, Remote connection is activated it's hard to put the finger on what's not OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same problem, finally figured out that a dynamic port entry has to be given along with the SQLExpress login .. ie 192.168.1.25\SQLEXPRESS,45490... then it allowed the login to happen.

We had installed a new SQLEXPRESS 2008 R2 (Windows 7 Professional Edition) in a new machine & was trying to connect to this DB from another machine from the mgmt studio and it was not connecting, nor was it connecting from any of the client machines.

We tried to check the SQLEXPRESS Browser / TCPIP was enabled and spent couple of hrs before we we figured out that the Dynamic port was causing this issue.

You can find this information, Open the SQLEXPRESS Configuration Manager, Select SQL Server Network Configuration on the left menu![Configuration Manager][1]
Select Protocol for SQLEXPRESS
You will find the TCPIP Enabled on the right side, click on the TCPIP and select properties
go to IPALL .. you will find the dynamic port info there.

btw, we tried installation on two HP PCs had the same issue & was solved with the dynamic port, while when we tried the installation on the ACer PC - did not get this dynamic port issue - so not really sure if it had anything to do with the OEM OS setup !?

However, the above solved our situation.

Answer (score 5):

Last time this has happened to me, it was because I forgot about the `SQL Server Browser` service.

Comment: No luck, I've started SQL Browser and it still does not connect.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try these steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx ?

SQLEXPRESS is named instance, so it doesnt listen on 1433 port (it's for default instance). Try this:

1. Disable firewall
2. Start SQL Browser
3. Try to connect from remote machine

Comment: I did precisely what's in that page, and re-check the firewall run this from an admin console "netsh advfirewall AllProfiles state off". It does not work.

Comment: Another advice : If it still fails, you may replace server\instance with tcp:server\instance and/or np:server\instance and see if it succeeds with either TCP or NP protocol. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx)

Comment: Tried with tcp:server\sqlexpress tcp:192.168.1.18\sqlexpress same with np: no luck, SQL Browser is working, firewall is disabled and I even cannot see it when I browse from remote Management Studio. As for hardware firewall, it was working fine before I uninstall it this morning, I can ping the server from the remote server and it's all in the same subnet so traffic pass directly without being filtered. It's a non-sense so far.

Comment: You wrote: "I ensure that the port was OK on Properties of TCP/IP of the SQL Server Configuration, there were no value at first, so I manual entered 1433, stop, start the server, try to connect." Did you remove this value and set 0 back?

Comment: Yes I did, at this moment everything is back as original Remote connection on the SQL Server Options > Connections, I removed those manually entered port on TCP/IP of SQL Configuration (TCP/IP and Named Pipe are enabled). Firewall is disabled, can ping the server via its name from the remote server

Comment: Just in case (I can't find source right now)- setting port number to 0 and leaving blank was supposed to have different meanings

Comment: And one final solution - did you reboot? I've once had a problem with server configuration and reboot did help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6671/discussion-between-bartekr-and-dominic-st-pierre)

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by using the server configuration manager to disable the dynamic port (blank = disable), and fix the port to 1433